# Tensorflow: Does a tflite file contain data about the model architecture? (graph?)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Does a tflite file contain data about the model architecture? A graph that shows what operations there where between the weights and features and biases, what kind of layers (linear or convolutional etc), size of layers, and what activation functions are there in-between the layers?
For example a graph you get with graphviz, that contains all the information, or does a tflite file only contain the final weights of the model after training?

I am working on a project with image style transfer. I wanted to do some research on an existing project, and see what parameters work better. The project I am looking at is here:

https://tfhub.dev/sayakpaul/lite-model/arbitrary-image-stylization-inceptionv3-dynamic-shapes/int8/transfer/1

I can download a tflite file, but I don't know much about these files. If they have the architecture I need, how do I read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFLite flatbuffer files contain the model structure as well. For example, there are a subgraph concept in TFLite, which corresponds to the function concept in the programming language and the operator nodes also represent a graph node, which takes inputs and generates outputs. By using the Netron application, the model architecture can be visualized.